# Initial problem with quick build

Tags: errors

I have just installed MikTeX Console with TeXworks and then Texmaker that is the tool I want to use.
I have just started with the configuration (Option-->Commands-->PDF embed; QuickBuild-->PdfLaTeX + PDF View) and I was writing the very initial 2 lines, and tried the quick build. Result: nothing happened! No error messages, nothing and the mouse arrow is a circle as always working, but doing nothing.

This is the simple line I have input:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
First latex trial.
Supposing $(x+1)/2=0$ we will get $x=1$.
\end{document}
```

I've tried to uninstall and install another version, same problem. Am I doing anything wrong? I have Windows 10.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check if the binary file for `pdflatex` is well configured in the editor.

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you save the file as `.tex` before build it?

Comment: Yes, the save was the first action before start writing the code. HOw can I check th ebinary file?

Comment: You should be able to see the paths for binaries in the Options>Configure menu.

Comment: Do you mean this one? pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex